# Google Sites Drawing Reload

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-sites

Total noob here with almost zero understanding of Google Apps Script or coding in general.

I was looking for a way to force a reload of a google sites page. This ([reload page google apps script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13971146/reload-page-google-apps-script)) makes it look like that can't be done, so I want to try and reload just the google drawing embedded in the site if possible.

I tried to use a javascript iFrame reload:

> window.setInterval("reloadIFrame();", 30000); function reloadIFrame() { document.frames["frameNameHere"].location.reload(); }

But I don't think google sites supports this our I got it wrong somewhere.

I can't figure out what the correct Apps Script would be to force the page to reload(pull from the server) the drawing in question. The code for the drawing looks like this:

> img
>   src="https://www.google.com/chart?chc=sites&cht=d&chdp=sites&chl=%5B%5BGoogle+drawing'%3D20'f%5Cv'a%5C%3D0'10'%3D999'0'dim'%5Cbox1'b%5CF6F6F6'fC%5CF6F6F6'eC%5C0'sk'%5C%5B%2211.30.15%22'%5D'a%5CV%5C%3D12'f%5C%5DV%5Cta%5C%3D10'%3D0'%3D1000'%3D347'dim'%5C%3D10'%3D10'%3D1000'%3D347'vdim'%5Cbox1'b%5Cva%5CF6F6F6'fC%5CC8C8C8'eC%5C'a%5C%5Do%5CLauto'f%5C&sig=0bBZl8MyZOx5b3ykHuUS35Gb8iE"
>   data-origsrc="1mUFhZeas0mFl52FpqC_EgflRn6P3TixsOxMAXI-_Fgo"
>   data-type="sketchy"
>   data-props="align:left;borderTitle:11.30.15;height:350;objectTitle:11.30.15;showBorder:false;showBorderTitle:false;width:1000;wrap:false;" width="1000" height="350"
>   style="display:block;text-align:left;margin-right:auto;">

It's located in my google drive and I just used the google sites tools to embed it, I didn't code it. The drawing is edited constantly throughout the day and I need the changes to appear while viewing with out requiring a page refresh.

Can anyone help me with where and what code could be used to reload the drawing? Even better would be if I could set an interval (say every 5 minutes) for the refresh. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you can create an XML gadget that reloads the Google Sites Page.

Try this one (found quickly)
http://www.k8oms.net/refresh

Comment: but its kind of ugly. much better to write an apps script gadget that just refreshes the embedded image.

Comment: This works, and as Zig says is kind of ugly. But I'm not really worried about aesthetics as much as function. I just hid it at the bottom of the page. Thanks so much for your help!